# jQuery AJAX GET request returning “parsererror” error response message

Tags: sitecore-api, webapi, javascript, ajax

In a scope of Sitecore Web project an API Contoller is used. Got the following response error message during jQuery AJAX GET API request:

[image: jQuery AJAX message error]

On a back-end side I use IHttpActionResult action method that returns **Json** object such as **return Json(model)**.

An API Action method looks like below:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid id)
{
  var targetItem = Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(id)); var model = new List<T>();

  //business logic where appropriate data<T> (simple properties such as Guid, string) is added to model. 

  return Json(model); 
}
```

and AJAX call function looks like below:

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: "GET", 
  url: url, 
  dataType: "json", 
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
  success: function(response) { }, 
  error (req,err){ //here I got "parsererror" message }
}
```

During this call the following **Exception** is executed:

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message: Attempt to retrieve context object of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.PageContext' from empty stack. Source: Sitecore.Mvc at Sitecore.Mvc.Common.ContextService.Peek[T]() at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcPipelineArgs.get_PageContext() at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.Request.RequestEnd.AddPageExtenders.Process(RequestEndArgs args)
```

This issue is caused on Production CD server. In localhost everything is OK. Any ideas how I can avoid this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange! Can you add some more specifics about the call you're making and your code that receives it? Code snippets will help, too.

Comment: @DanSinclair

Sure, below you can see API Action method:

`public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid id)
 {
    var targetItem = Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(id));
    var model = new List<T>();
           
    //business logic
    where appropriate data<T> (simple properties such as Guid, string) is added 
    to model.
            
   return Json(model);
  }`

Comment: @DanSinclair and AJAX call function:



`$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(response) {
            },
            error (req,err){
                //here I got parsererror message
            }`

Comment: just discovered that during this call the following Exception is executed:

`Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Attempt to retrieve context object of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.PageContext' from empty stack.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Common.ContextService.Peek[T]()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcPipelineArgs.get_PageContext()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.Request.RequestEnd.AddPageExtenders.Process(RequestEndArgs args)`

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add this information? It will be more useful to potential answerers in the context of your original question.

Comment: sure, just added those notes to my question. thanks for suggestion!

Comment: Might want to add the stack trace of the error you received, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88106/discussion-between-vadzim-papko-and-dan-sinclair).